# How do you use bootstrap with Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to use bootstrap with Cloud9 IDE but all of the tutorials use standard text editors to access the bootstrap dist files. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud9 is just like a local development environment. In other words, Cloud9 is just like you're developing on your own computer. Download Bootstrap files to your Cloud9 workspace then reference them from your html file, just like you would with a standard text editor.